# Using p:inplace in PrimeFaces

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

While using a `<p:inplace>` in PrimeFaces (5.0), the position at which the save and the cancel buttons are displayed looks appropriate, when a `<p:inplace>` is used with a `<p:inputText>` but those buttons look ugly, when a `<p:inplace>` is used with other components.

Given below just some examples.

```
<p:inplace id="text" editor="true" label="Text">
    <p:inputText/>
</p:inplace>

<br/><br/><br/>

<p:inplace id="textArea" editor="true" label="TextArea">
    <p:inputTextarea/>
</p:inplace>

<br/><br/><br/>

<p:inplace id="list" editor="true" label="List">
    <p:selectOneMenu>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="List Item 1"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="List Item 2"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="List Item 3"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</p:inplace>
```

It displays these components as can be seen in the following picture.

[image]

As can be seen, the buttons are not lined up properly with their respective components except `<p:inputText>`.

They should be displayed vertically middle/centre (or at least perfect baseline) to the right of each component as done with  `<p:inputText>` in the first example.

Is there a way to customize this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to adjust based on the child component.

In your case there're three components, `inputText` `inputTextArea` and `selectOneMenu`, now both `inputText` and `inputTextArea` have `ui-inputfield` CSS class, and the `selectOneMenu` has `ui-selectonemenu` that said you can adjust as the following:

```css
.ui-inplace .ui-selectonemenu, .ui-inplace .ui-inputfield {
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a cleaner solution, but you could use CSS to fix the positioning of the button container, using the styleClass property on the inline element like this:

XHTML:

```
<p:inplace id="list" styleClass="customInplaceListStyle" editor="true" label="List">
    <p:selectOneMenu>
         <f:selectItem itemLabel="List Item 1"/>
         <f:selectItem itemLabel="List Item 2"/>
         <f:selectItem itemLabel="List Item 3"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</p:inplace>
```

CSS:

```
.customInplaceListStyle.ui-inplace .ui-inplace-editor {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 8px;
}
```

Tested in FF and IE9

Comment: having fixed value for the bottom is rather a "static" solution, basically if the height of the selectOneMenu is changed you have to change that static value.